# Oracle SQL: Setting the appropriate date value for the given condition

Tags: sql, oracle

**First of all, I am very very new to SQL.**

I would like to convert the table format as follows:

```
--------------------------------
|      ID      |   create_date |
--------------------------------
|       1      |   2020-03-01  |
|       1      |   2020-04-01  |
|       2      |   2019-03-15  |
|       2      |   2020-04-20  |
|       2      |   2021-05-30  |
|       3      |   2022-04-01  |
--------------------------------
```

on such:

```
-----------------------------------------------
|      ID      |  create_date  |   to_date    |
-----------------------------------------------
|       1      |  2020-03-01   |  2020-03-31  |
|       1      |  2020-04-01   |  9999-12-31  |
|       2      |  2019-03-15   |  2020-04-19  |
|       2      |  2020-04-20   |  2021-05-29  |
|       2      |  2021-05-30   |  9999-12-31  |
|       3      |  2022-04-01   |  9999-12-31  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

**using Oracle SQL.**

As you can see, I have records with the same customers (`id`) but different dates (`create_date`).

I want to create a new column (let's call it `to_date`) in which I will have the appriopriate value:

```
1. if first `id` is the same as second `id`, put the same date as in second row but with -1 day
```

<so in first row it will be '31.03.2020', beacause in second row there is '01.04.2020'>

```
2. if first `id` is NOT the same as second `id`, put the date `31.12.9999` (or `9999-12-31`)
```

<or in other words, put '31.12.9999' for every unique id that has the biggest create_date>

In Python it would look more or less like this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.ID[i] == df.ID[i+1]:
        to_date[i] = create_date[i+1]-1
    else:
        to_date[i] = '9999-12-31'
    if df.ID[len(df)]:
        to_date[i] = '9999-12-31'
```

**How can I achieve that in Oracle SQL?**

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to do it all in sql, you can use `LEAD`the get the next date using "ID" as Partition

> ```
> SELECt
> "ID","create_date"
> , COALESCE(LEAD("create_date") OVER(PARTITION By "ID" ORDEr BY "create_date") - INTERVAL '1' DAY,
>  DATE  '9999-12-31') 
> as "created_at"
> FROM
> tab1
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | create_date | created_at
> -: | :---------- | :---------
>  1 | 01-MAR-20   | 31-MAR-20 
>  1 | 01-APR-20   | 31-DEC-99 
>  2 | 15-MAR-19   | 19-APR-20 
>  2 | 20-APR-20   | 29-MAY-21 
>  2 | 30-MAY-21   | 31-DEC-99 
>  3 | 01-APR-22   | 31-DEC-99
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=096cba95da1079dc55f555b6f8197561)*